# Managed Metadata Navigation - How do you make quicklaunch work contextually like structural nav quicklaunch?

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, contextualscope

I've tried to use the new Managed Metadata navigation on our new SP2013 site, and it works great for global navigation. However, I have spent hours trying to figure out how to get the quicklaunch navigation working in a contextual way similar to how structural quick launch navigation works. I cannot find hardly any documentation on getting this to work in a **contextual** way. Is this even possible? If so what steps are required to achieve something analogous to what we had before with structural nav?

**EDIT:**

One additional detail on this that is important is if you use simple links. I found that it doesn't work unless you use full qualified Url's `protocol` + `hostname` + `path`. Simple relative links or links with the `~sitecollection` token do not seem to work (even though it says they are supported). The url asset picker dialog (browse) doesn't give you these url's and good luck training an end user to fix the url.

Term driven navigation doesn't seem to have this limitation, but has a different limitation. When using term driven navigation, the sub-sites url segments must be completely different from the friendly term url segment or you will get 404's from the top down.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by contextual? Do you mean that you want to show the current site contents in the Quick Launch?

Comment: Yes, essentially I want it to detect where I'm at in the hierarchy and only show items below that not the whole global nav tree again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried implementing what you want to and it is working for me. Here are the steps I followed:

1) Create New Site Collection `http://spurl/sites/test`

2) Create Sub Site under that `http://spurl/sites/test/sub`

3) In the Term Store, created a a new TermGroup, TermSet and Term under it in the following order:

[image]

[image]

4) Also seen in the image, I assigned the terms to point to site collection and sub site respectively.

5) Went to `http://spurl/sites/test/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` and set the Current Navigation (Quick Launch) to Managed Metadata Navigation and selected the TermSet I created above. Saved the settings.

6) Now when I browse to `/sites/test`, in the quick launch I see `NavTerm1` and its child `child term` (and not `grand child` term)

[image]

7) And when I go to `/sites/test/sub`, in the quick launch, I do not see the entire tree again. I only see `child term` and the term below it `grand child term`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, that I'm trying to utilize `Term-Driven Pages with Friendly URL's`. I noticed that you are using Simple links, could you re-work your example with friendly term urls?

Comment: Just tested with changing the option to `Term-Driven Pages with Friendly URL's` and it works there too. Only thing is you have to go to The TermStore -> Term -> Term Driven Pages Tab -> Check the box "Change target page for this term" -> Put a page url in the text box e.g. `/sites/test/Pages/default.aspx` or `/sites/test/sub/Pages/default.aspx` and it should work the same way as described above.

Comment: Can there only be 2 levels of navigation shown?

Comment: Somehow i am not able to replicate the above . Seriously some setting is missing