# Sharepoint 2013 Current and Global Navigation

Tags: 2013, managed-navigation

I'm trying to configure Navigation to my site using managed metadata.
I have a site hierarchy looks like this:

-Level 1

-Level 1

---Level 2

---Level 2

---Level 2

------Level 3

------Level 3

-Level 1

...

I want the first level to be displayed in the global navigation control and once you click on a level that has children, the children will be displayed in the current navigation control. I want the global navigation to show only the first level and the current navigation to show the rest (second an third levels).

I've read [the overview in technet site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311.aspx) and it said that current navigation can show one or more levels of navigation that represent the next level of the navigation term set hierarchy based on the term that is selected in the global navigation control, however there is no example of how to configure the term set in order to to that.
I've tried to find an example in other blogs but with no success.

Can anyone please explain me how to do that or refer me to articles\blogs that shows that?

Comment: My answer for another question might be able to help you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74900/managed-metadata-navigation-how-do-you-make-quicklaunch-work-contextually-like

Comment: Thank you but if I understand your answer, once you click the first level in the global navigation you see all the levels sibling levels and their children (first and second) in the current navigation. I want to see only the next levels (second to third), just like it said in the technet overview in their "Simple managed navigation" example.

Comment: @Gil, Do we have any answer for this question?