# Displaying Full Navigation in QuickLaunch Menu

Tags: quick-launch

I'm using managed terms for QuickLaunch navigation in SP2013.  By default, it seems to only to display "contextual" links (that is, when I go to a sub-pages, the top level links and their children all disappear, leaving only sibling and child pages.) I saw [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74900/managed-metadata-navigation-how-do-you-make-quicklaunch-work-contextually-like) in which the asker seems to have the opposite problem.  How do I get the complete navigation to appear on all pages?

Comment: I possibly didn't quite understand your question, but could you accomplish this by setting `Structural Navigation: Display the navigation items below the current site` on your top site's navigation settings, and on sub sites (and on its sub sites, etc.) use the navigation option `Display the same navigation items as the parent site` (which has info text `(Parent is using Structural Navigation.)`.

Comment: Thanks @moe, but that option is not possible when using managed terms for navigation. We've resolved the issue by using a second "global navigation" component instead, but I'm still curious if there is a way to to this.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that before using a [Delegate Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms463169(v=office.14).aspx).

Assuming you already have a Farm or Sandbox solution, add an Empty Element to your project and put the following in your Elements.xml file.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control Id="QuickLaunchDataSource"
Sequence="50"
ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapDataSource"
ControlAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
    <Property Name="SiteMapProvider">CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider</Property>
    <Property Name="ID">QuickLaunchSiteMap</Property>
    <Property Name="TreatStartingNodeAsCurrent">true</Property>
    <Property Name="StartingNodeOffset">2</Property>
  </Control>
</Elements>
```

Adjust the StartingNodeOffset to the depth you want the navigation to start at.  In your case it might be 1.

Add the element to a Feature.

Deploy the solution.

Activate the feature.